# How can I distinct a set of rows with collapsed columns in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

for instance, I have this table

```
 id_plant | name | petals
----------+------+--------
 12       | foo  |   3   
 13       | bar  |   3    
 14       | foo  |   6
```

I need to distinct name and have an array with all the petals values.
So for the entry `foo` :

result :

```
 name | petals
------+--------
 foo  | [3, 6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_agg().`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
with my_table(id_plant, name, petals) as (
values
    (12, 'foo', 3),
    (13, 'bar', 3),
    (14, 'foo', 6)
)

select name, array_agg(petals) as petals
from my_table
group by name;

 name | petals 
------+--------
 foo  | {3,6}
 bar  | {3}
(2 rows)
```